# Can't convert binary UUID to String in NIFI

Tags: apache-nifi

I have the following problem - I download data from the database using QueryDatabaseTable, I receive the data in the avro-binary format, so then I use ConvertAvroToJson - everything converts nicely except the UUID field, I am left with the following json:

```
{
"Name":"Mary",
"Surname":"Smith",
"Mail":"m.smith@google.com",
"UUID":{
"bytes":"_ìª¨Ô¸¬I³Sñ])º\u000E•"
},
"City":"New York"
}
```

I tried to extract this UUID as an attribute and replace it with the :toString() method but it doesn't work, does anyone have an idea how to convert it to a string?